# passing a message from a worker thread to the main thread in an windowless ActiveX control

Tags: multithreading, activex, postmessage, ocx, worker-thread

I need to have a 2nd thread do some error checking which is working fine.   The main thread is a windowless ActiveX OCX.

What I’d like to do though is have that 2nd thread post a message back to the main thread.   I have set up a message map and a message handler.   From inside the 2nd thread, I use PostMessage to put the message up.   I know I get there and I know the message gets posted insofar as the return value on the PostMessage call results in a one  (TRUE).   I never see any response from the message handler.  It doesn't seem to be invoked whatsoever.

Code snippets from my Visual Studio 2012 ActiveX project:

```
//Message handler definition from the .h file:
protected:

   afx_msg LRESULT OnHSAmessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);



//From the .cpp file:

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CHSAObserver_ActiveXControlCtrl, COleControl)
       ON_OLEVERB(AFX_IDS_VERB_PROPERTIES, OnProperties)
       ON_MESSAGE(WM_HSAMESSAGE, &CHSAObserver_ActiveXControlCtrl::OnHSAmessage)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


// thread creation  (this works)
HSAWnd *pWnd = new HSAWnd(this);
hwndTarget = pWnd->Create();
HANDLE threadHandle = CreateThread(NULL,NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ThreadProc,  (LPVOID)     hwndTarget, NULL, &dwID);

//thread implementation
LONG ThreadProc(LPVOID pParam)
{
          BOOL status;
         //I know I get here the Postmessage call does not result
         //in the message handler being invoked
         MessageBox(_T("inside threadproc"));
         CHSAObserver_ActiveXControlCtrl *pCtrl = (CHSAObserver_ActiveXControlCtrl*)pParam;

         //post message using global HSAWnd
         status = PostMessage(hwndTarget, WM_HSAMESSAGE,(WPARAM)NULL,(LPARAM)NULL);

         //post message using Class window  (here for testing only)
         //status = PostMessage (pCtrl->m_hWnd, WM_HSAMESSAGE,(WPARAM)NULL,(LPARAM)NULL);

    return TRUE;
}


afx_msg LRESULT CHSAObserver_ActiveXControlCtrl::OnHSAmessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
         //this never happens
         MessageBox(_T("message posted"));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMO, your question is confusing as is, consider improving it. *"The main thread is a windowless ActiveX OCX"*, and suddenly there's `hwndTarget` window (or not? and what is `HSAWnd`?). Anyway, a windowless ActiveX control can only receive a Windows message via `IOleInPlaceSiteWindowless::OnDefWindowMessage`, and only if the container actually forwards the message to it.

Comment: @Noseratio HSAWnd is a class I created from Cwnd.   I was trying to attempt to create a hidden window to which I could post messages.  HSAWnd is an instance of that class.  I would like my message handler to respond to messages posted to HSAWnd.   Per your suggestion, I will look at OnDefWindowMessage.  Thank you.

Comment: Just noticed I had two typos: HSAWnd is a class I created from Cwnd. I was trying to create a hidden window to which I could post messages. hwndTarget is an instance of that class. I would like my message handler to respond to messages posted to hwndTarget.

Comment: So have you tried moving `ON_MESSAGE(WM_HSAMESSAGE,...)` into `HSAWnd`? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the code of `HSAWnd`, but I think the problem is, your message map is declared inside `CHSAObserver_ActiveXControlCtrl` class, and that's where you have the entry for `WM_HSAMESSAGE`. At the same time, you post the message to the window created by an instance of the `HSAWnd` class, which is separate from `CHSAObserver_ActiveXControlCtrl` and has nothing in common with its message map.

Thus, `HSAWnd` should have the message map entry for `WM_HSAMESSAGE` instead of `CHSAObserver_ActiveXControlCtrl`. I expect it would work then.

On a side note, `PostMessage` is an async API. You should consider accounting for the case when you worker thread events will come in faster than `HSAWnd` may be processing `WM_HSAMESSAGE` messages.

If you want to post messages from the worker thread to *the UI thread* asynchronously, a hidden window and `PostMessage` is pretty much the only choice.

If you're OK with doing it synchronously, you could use `SendMessage` instead. Alternatively, you can use COM inter-thread marshaling, in which case you don't need to create a hidden window explicitly. Define a private interfaces on your ActiveX control (e.g., `IPrivate`, make sure it's a part of the type library), then marshal it to the worker thread with `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` / `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` and call any methods of `IPrivate` inside the worker thread on the proxy object returned by `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream`. There are some good examples of this approach on the web, like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9506/Understanding-The-COM-Single-Threaded-Apartment-Pa).

Comment: You are correct.  I do not have a message map entry for WM_HSAMESSAGE in my HSAWnd class.  I will make that modification and report my results.

Comment: @PhilsterNH, so that did not help, did it?

Comment: No it did not help.   I still do not see any response from the message handler.   Per your suggestion, I created a message map and a message handler in the HSAWnd class and that did not help.  I removed it from my main class CHSAObserver_ActiveXControlCtrl as well.

Comment: @PhilsterNH, there's still a bug in your code. You pass `hwndTarget` as param to `CreateThread`. Then inside the thread you cast `pParam` to `CHSAObserver_ActiveXControlCtrl`. So you cast a window handle to C++ object, ouch. You probably wanted to pass `pWnd` into the thread, rather than `hwndTarget`, then do `PostMessage(pWnd->m_hWnd, ...)` inside the thread.